# Adding Scale Breaks to an ssrs bar graph

Tags: sql, graph, ssrs-2008-r2

[a pic of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMQ2q.png)

as you can see in the posted picture it is graph basically illegible. so 
is there a way to put breaks in an ssrs bar graph?

Comment: what do you mean by breaks? do you mean page breaks?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking for is to have spaces between the individual graphs on your page.

You should be able to go to the properties pane (usually in the bottom right corner). There look for custom attributes and then find the point width. There are other setting here as well.

Make sure you have selected your graph before going to the settings.